# Extract the brackets {} from newtxmath

Tags: fonts, math-fonts

I'm now using `mtpro2`. However, I prefer the brackets from `newtxmath`. I think  it is more coherent with Chinese. How can I extract the brackets `{` and `}` from `newtxmath`? It seems to be a tremendous amount of work..

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openany,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage[margin=2cm, top=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[subscriptcorrection,nofontinfo,zswash,mtphrb]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\{x\mid 3x+2y<6\},~\left\{\frac{y}{x}\mid x\in\mathbb{Q},~y\in\mathbb{Q}\right\}$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontEncoding{LMS}{}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{ntxsymbols}{LMS}{ntxsy}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{ntxsymbols}{bold}{LMS}{ntxsy}{b}{n}

\DeclareFontEncoding{LMX}{}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{ntxlsymbols}{LMX}{ntxexx}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{ntxlsymbols}{bold}{LMX}{ntxexx}{b}{n}

\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lbrace}{\mathopen}{ntxsymbols}{102}{ntxlsymbols}{8}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rbrace}{\mathclose}{ntxsymbols}{103}{ntxlsymbols}{9}

\begin{document}


\begin{center}
  $\{ a + b \}$
\end{center}

\[ \biggl\{ \frac{a}{b} + \frac{c}{d} \biggr\} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]